# PHP - how to put an banner between 4 items from my database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm an beginner in php/msql, and need help to solve this problem:

I have 4 items in my tabel, now I need to show those four items in order by ID. But now I want to add an Google Adsense banner between the second and third item. Which code should I use?

My page must look like this:

> [ item 1 ]
>   [ item 2 ] 
>   [ banner ]
>   [ item 3 ]
>   [ item 4 ]

My code:

```
function getenqeute(){
    $q = "SELECT * FROM tblenquetes ORDER BY id";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);
    $amountenqeutes = mysqli_num_rows($r);
    $enqeutenow = 1;
    while($enquete = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
        if($enqeutenow==$amountenqeutes){
            echo '';
        }else{
            echo '';
        }
        $desc = htmlentities(htmlspecialchars($enquete['enquetedescription']));
        $hash_tag = md5($enquete['enqueteid'] . date('d-m-Y H:i:s',time()));
        $date = date('Y-m-d', time());
        $q = "INSERT INTO tblcallback VALUES('', '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '".$hash_tag."', '".$date."', '".$enquete['enqueteid']."', '0')";
        mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

        $link = 'http://domain.nl/enquete?enq='.$enquete['enquetelink'].'&publ_tag='.$hash_tag;
        echo'
    <div class="enquete-item" onclick="location.href=\''.$link.'\';">
        <a rel="nofollow" href="'.$link.'">
            <img src="'.$enquete['enqueteimagelink'].'" alt="'.$enquete['enquetename'].'"></img>
        </a>
        <p><b><a rel="nofollow" href="'.$link.'">'.$enquete['enquetename'].'</a></b><br/>
        '.$desc.'</p>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>';
        $enqeutenow++;
    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You really should separate your business logic from your presentation logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
if ($enqeutenow == 3)
    echo GoogleAd
```

Comment: I can try it, where i need to put this? (sorry, im not good in php)

Comment: Anywhere before echoing the item, or after `$enqeutenow++;`, or use 2 instead of 3 just after echoing the item.